# Proper structure - Twilio Callback

Tags: twilio, sms, callbackurl

I have been having some success sending sms messages with Twilio via curl. Now I am wanting to implement the callback url to track the status of the message.. I cannot seem to get the call back to work [image]

I have tried encoding it in JSON and also appending it as parameter and I havent been able to have any success.. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not JSON, it is sent as urlencoded (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

[Where do I find the specifications for inbound HTTP requests to my server?](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/webhooks-faq#where-do-i-find-the-specifications-for-inbound-http-requests-to-my-server)

Comment: Thanks Alan.. That worked.. I converted all of the POST parameters are urlencoded and it work.. thanks again